# DoCmd.RunSQL error out, need better variables?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

All of my variables work, I can make each variable's value show up in a text box and the code runs smoothly. However, when I try to update table1, the DoCmd.RunSQL line errors out. Maybe because adding a value to ID=Y make Y no longer true?

```
Y = DMax("[ID]", "Table1", "Len(Due_date) = 0")
X = DMin("[ID]", "Table1")
A = DMin("[ID]", "Table1", "Len(Due_date) > 0")

B = DLookup("[Duration]", "Table1", "[ID] = " & Y)
C = DLookup("[Due_date]", "Table1", "[ID] = " & A)
E = DateAdd("d", -B, C)


 Dim SQL As String

        SQL = "UPDATE Table1 " & _
          "SET Table1.Due_date = '" & E & "'" & _
         "WHERE Table1.ID = '" & Y & "'"


DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: Date type field requires # delimiter not apostrophe. Number type field does not require any delimiter. Need a space in front of WHERE so text does not run together: `" WHERE `. Suggest CurrentDb.Execute instead of DoCmd.RunSQL. Also: `-1 * B`.

Comment: Correction, apparently `-1 * B` is not needed, `-B` should work.

Comment: Are you declaring any of these variables anywhere? Consider declaring them if you aren't, and using `Option Explicit` too. What's the error exactly?

Comment: Seems `Y` would be a `Long`? (or whatever the type of `[ID]` is) - if that's the case, you should probably drop the single quotes around `Y` in your query. And use `#` date literal markers instead of single quotes around `E`, since `E` looks like it's a date; single quotes are for strings. Declare your variables with an explicit type, e.g. `Dim Y As Long`, or better, `Dim updateId As Long`. Use meaningful names, not single-letter random identifiers.

Comment: Do any of the records have Null in fields? The conditional criteria expressions with Len() should fail if encounter Null. Won't return True or False, just Null. DMin and DMax will still return values, but the Len() criteria will not restrict the search. So if Due_date is a date/time type, Len() is not useful as a date/time field cannot be an empty string, it can be Null. Use `"IsNull(Due_date)"`.

Comment: Or when testing for Null in queries or domain aggregate criteria: `"Due_date Is Null"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the error arises because your date `E` appears formatted using regional settings in the SQL string.

You could use the BuildCriteria method to create a SQL string of the form `fieldname ComparisonOperator CompareExpression`, for example `Due_date=#10/27/2018#`. Although `CStr` converts a value to a string using regional settings, BuildCriteria takes that regional string and turns it into the correcly formatted string for use in a SQL command, just like the query designer does when you enter criteria using your regional format. Your code could look like this (variable `X` isn't used):

```
Y = DMax("ID", "Table1", BuildCriteria("Due_date", dbDate, "Null"))
A = DMin("ID", "Table1", BuildCriteria("Due_date", dbDate, "Not Null"))

B = DLookup("Duration", "Table1", BuildCriteria("ID", dbLong, CStr(Y)))
C = DLookup("Due_date", "Table1", BuildCriteria("ID", dbLong, CStr(A)))
E = DateAdd("d", -B, C)

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "UPDATE Table1 " & _
    "SET " & BuildCriteria("Due_date", dbDate, CStr(E)) & " " & _
    "WHERE " & BuildCriteria("ID", dbLong, CStr(Y))

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: I had to change the Due_date field from " " to Null, but after that the code above worked, thank you!

Comment: Although I dont't know what you had to change I'm glad that it worked.  :)